# Providing a user an option to view the output in the form of a select list i.e. viewing the output one by one

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed an rshiny app which displays a table and a plot as output for a given city, which comes as an input from user. The thing is now I am giving user the flexibility to enter more than one city as input.
So what i want to do now is to display the output in such a way so that the user has a select list which displays the output based on the value selected by the user.

For ex a user enter 3 city now 3 table and 3 plots have been computed in the observe event, I want the user to select the city based on which the output will be displayed.

Sample code would be something like;

```
observeEvent(input$get, {
some operations...
output$city_output<- renderDataTable(samp_data)
}
)
```

And I would need the ouput to be like

```
selectInput('city','Select the city to be displayed',samp_data$city)
```

Based on user selection the data table for that city should be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this using the `renderUI` command?

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Test App"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         checkboxGroupInput("City",label = "Choose a city", 
                     choices = c("London","Paris","Hamburg"),
                     selected="London")
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(

         uiOutput("ReactiveUI"),
         textOutput("Final")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
   output$ReactiveUI <- renderUI(
     selectInput("ReactiveUI",
                                 label="Choose one of your choices",
                                 choices = input$City,
                                 selected="London"))
   output$Final <- renderText({paste("you selected",input$ReactiveUI)})


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This works because by using the `renderUI` command we have access to the values stored in `input$City` as we are in the `server.r` file.

**EDIT:**

To elaborate on `renderUI`, this command pairs with `uiOutput` (it's ui.R counterpart, like `renderText` is to `textOutput`). The `renderUI` command moves the construction of a UI element from `ui.R` to `server.R`. This is useful because we can not do much "programming" in `ui.R` but we can in `server.R`. We also can't access anything stored in the `input` list while in `ui.R`. To put it simply, by creating our UI element in `server.R`, we allow the UI of our applications to respond to other user inputs.

In this example, we take advantage of the ability to see other inputs by setting the choices of our dropdown to the input selected by the `checkboxGroupInput`

Comment: Hey Michael the solution works perfectly! I am new to rshiny so if could you also elaborate a bit on the concept of renderUI used in this specific case then that would be helpful for my future endeavors.

Comment: Just a follow up question, is there any way that I can show London as the default city in the output i.e. the output select list should display London by default and so should the render text, the user then can change the select list output option to any other city if he/she wishes to see output for some other city

Comment: hi @bakas, I have added a little more detail about `renderUI` and I have also edited my code to have the `selected` parameter in my two inputs. I think it behaves as you want.